# Not able to Use RandomAccessFile file for rw mode only in case when writing a file in sd card

Tags: java, android, randomaccessfile

Below is my sdcard path of a start.mp4 file. I am able to get this file in read mode but not able to open in `rw` mode. I have given runtime permissions also. It throws a exception:

```
/storage/3263-6232/piyush/Download/start.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Code:

```
String sdCardPath = "/storage/3263-6232/piyush/Download/start.mp4"; 
File file = new File(sdCardPath );
try{

RandomAccessFile rfs = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

rfs.seek(file.length());
rfs.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the above code I have taken `sdcardpath` to a file which exists in sdcard.
Than after that whenever I tried to open that file in outputstream using `RandomAccessFile` it gives `FilenotFound Exception`:

```
/storage/3263-6232/piyush/Download/start.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: So you don't have write access to the file. Define 'given runtime permissions'. And why exactly do you need write access to a .mp4 file?

Comment: I need to encrypt the file and change the first 10 bits of that file. I am able to do the same thing when did in internal memory but not in sd card. @EJP

Answer (score 0):

Does your `Manifest` looks like this? 
The `uses-permission` tag needs to be outside the application tag

`<manifest>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        ...
        <application>
            ...
            <activity> 
                ...
            </activity>
        </application>
</manifest>`

PS: If you are using Post M device for testing then make sure you ask `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission before doing any operation on you file.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Storage location to /storage/3263-6232/Android/data/`<Your package Name>`/files  will solve your issue

Above Path is only have write access for related third party apps, elsewhere you can read the file but can't write new file.

Or you need to apply Storage Access Framework for getting write permission.

For more details you can visit 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html